# How can I change HTML attribute names with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

I would like to change all the names of the attributes where `class="testingCase"` throughout all my whole html document.

e.g. Change:

```
<a class="testingCase" href="#" title="name of testing case">Blabla</a>
<a class="testingCase" href="#" title="name of another testing case">Bloo</a>
```

To this:

```
<a class="testingCase" href="#" newTitleName="name of testing case">Blabla</a>`
<a class="testingCase" href="#" newTitleName="name of another testing case">Bloo</a>`
```

I was thinking of a find and replace but that seems a lot of code for something so easy. Is there a jQuery function for this or a simple method?

Answer (score 50):

There is no built-in method/function to "rename" an attribute in javascript, but you can create new attributes and remove other ones...

```js
$('a.testingCase[title]').each(function() {
  var $t = $(this);
  $t.attr({
      newTitleName: $t.attr('title')
    })
    .removeAttr('title');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="testingCase" href="#" title="name of testing case">Blabla</a>
<a class="testingCase" href="#" title="name of another testing case">Bloo</a>
```

Edit: added in the bit that makes it only select `a` elements with class="testingCase"

Answer (score 9):

I don't think you can change an attribute name but what you can do is :

- get all the `<a>` tags with a title attribute;
- foreach of them, create a newTitleName attribute with the same value as the title;
- then delete the title attribute.

JQuery let you do that with builtin functions this way :

```
/* get all <a> with a "title" attribute that are testingCase
then apply an anonymous function on each of them */

$('a.testingCase[title]').each(function() {   

    /* create a jquery object from the <a> DOM object */
    var $a_with_title = $(this);    

    /* add the new attribute with the title value */
    $a_with_title.attr("newTitleName", $a_with_title.getAttribute('title'));

    /* remove the old attribute */
    $a_with_title.removeAttr('title'); 

});
```

Answer (score 8):

A little later but this [link](http://wowmotty.blogspot.de/2011/10/jquery-rename-attribute-renameattr.html) has a great jquery function extension:

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
  renameAttr: function( name, newName, removeData ) {
    var val;
    return this.each(function() {
      val = jQuery.attr( this, name );
      jQuery.attr( this, newName, val );
      jQuery.removeAttr( this, name );
      // remove original data
      if (removeData !== false){
        jQuery.removeData( this, name.replace('data-','') );
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Example

```
// $(selector).renameAttr(original-attr, new-attr, removeData);
 
// removeData flag is true by default
$('#test').renameAttr('data-test', 'data-new' );
 
// removeData flag set to false will not remove the
// .data("test") value
$('#test').renameAttr('data-test', 'data-new', false );
```

I DID NOT WRITE THIS. BUT I DID TEST IS WITH JQ 1.10. THE CODE IS FROM THE LINK.

Comment: This solution is fit my problem, when you need to rename attribute dynamically like this
`$(this).attr({ 'data-parent' + file.idx: $(this).attr('data-parent_cbidx') }).removeAttr('data-parent_cbidx');`  which is not working and then i change to this
`$(this).renameAttr('data-parent_cbidx', 'data-parent_' + file.idx, false);`

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simple jquery-style plugin that gives you a renameAttr method:

```
// Rename an entity attribute
jQuery.fn.renameAttr = function(oldName, newName) {
    var args = arguments[0] || {}; 
    var o = $(this[0]) 

       o
        .attr(
            newName, o.attr(oldName)
        )
        .removeAttr(oldName)
        ;
};
```

There is also [this example](http://wowmotty.blogspot.com/2011/10/jquery-rename-attribute-renameattr.html) which adds an option to remove the data for the old attribute.

Answer (score 1):

One liner

```
$('selector').replaceWith($('selector')[0].outerHTML.replace("oldName=","newName="));
```

worked great for me when I needed to strip a prefix from all of my attributes

```
$('selector').replaceWith($('selector')[0].outerHTML.(/prefix\-/g,""));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input class="form-control" type="date" value="<?=$arRes["FORM"]["STAT"]?>" name="STAT" <?=($arRes["MIN_DATE"]) ? "min='".$arRes["MIN_DATE"]."'" : "" ?> <?=($arRes["MAX_DATE"]) ? "max='".$arRes["MAX_DATE"]."'" : "" ?>>

$(document).on("change", "#chek_min_max", function(event){
            var input_field = $("[name=STAT]");
            if(event.target.checked){
                input_field.attr("min", input_field.attr('data-min')).removeAttr('data-min');
                input_field.attr("max", input_field.attr('data-max')).removeAttr('data-max');
            }
            if(!event.target.checked){
                input_field.attr("data-min", input_field.attr('min')).removeAttr('min');
                input_field.attr("data-max", input_field.attr('max')).removeAttr('max');
            }
        });
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

same answer as @nickf but cleaner code:

```
$('a.testingCase[title]').each(function() {
    var curElem = $(this);
    curElem.attr("newTitleName", curElem.attr('title')).removeAttr('title');
});
```

Answer (score -2):

It works for me!

```
$('input[name="descricao"]').attr('name', 'title');
```