# jquery rename all attributes

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I change HTML attribute names with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/317170/how-can-i-change-html-attribute-names-with-jquery)

I have a large/complex form with different available questions based on the previously selected questions.

To try and keep this a little organised I have a few duplicate inputs with the same name. This creates the problem where input further down the page even if they are hidden are overwriting the visible inputs.

To prevent this I have set all hidden inputs with `data-name` instead of `name` attribute.

**Questions**
How can I change the attribute name. E.g:

```
<input data-name="phone" value="" />
<input data-name="email" value="" />

To
<input name="phone" value="" />
<input name="email" value="" />
```

Comment: Are the results when Googling `jquery rename name attribute` not useful? e.g. this: [How can I change HTML attribute names with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/317170)

Comment: I think his question is "how can I change attribute with duplicate value?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the above HTML mark-up, I'd suggest:

```
$('input').each(
    function(i,el){
        var data = $(el).data();
        for (datum in data) {
            if (!el[datum]) {
                el[datum] = data[datum];
                el.removeAttribute('data-' + datum);
            }
        }
    });​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/F85u3/).

This uses the jQuery `data()` method to create an object with the data, if any exists, attached to the current jQuery object being iterated over by the `each()` method.

Effectively, in the above example, the `if` checks that the current element doesn't already has an attribute of the same name (so the `name` won't be overwritten if it already exists) and, if it doesn't exist, creates that attribute/property.

To explicitly overwrite a pre-existing attribute:

```
$('input').each(
    function(i, el) {
        var data = $(el).data();
        for (datum in data) {
            el[datum] = data[datum];
            el.removeAttribute('data-' + datum);
        }
    });​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/F85u3/1/).

References:

- [`data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/).
- [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/).
- [`removeAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.removeAttribute).

Answer (score 2):

```
$('input[data-name]').each(function(){
    $(this).attr('name', $(this).attr('data-name')); //does the switch
    $(this).removeAttr('data-name'); //clears out the old one if you need to
});
```

Comment: Rather than just having code, include an explanation as well.

Comment: There is simple clarification in the comments in the code. If you need clarification on what a jQuery function is doing, that's what documentation is for.