# change data-attribute using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, attributes, custom-data-attribute

How can I change

```
<div data-300=""></div>
```

to

```
<div data-500=""></div>
```

using jquery?

I don't want to remove the attribute and replace it as it contains data I need I just need to change the '300' to '500'.

Comment: You will need to replace it, but that doesn't mean you need to lose the value.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/317170/how-can-i-change-html-attribute-names-with-jquery

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not generic at all, but it should do the job

```
var $target = $('div[data-300]'),
    oldData = $target.data('300');

$target.removeAttr('data-300').attr({ 'data-500': oldData });
```

Comment: Legend! Thanks for the speedy answer!

Answer (score 3):

Here's a function you can use:

```
function attrChangeName(elem, attr, new_attr) {
  var data = $(elem).attr(attr);
  $(elem).attr(new_attr, data);
  $(elem).removeAttr(attr);
}
```

Comment: That simplifies things a lot. Thanks! In the interest of making the code easier to read (it would just make more sence to me when reading through code) would it be possible to make it so the call could be something like this:   $('element').attrChangeName(attr, new_attr);

Comment: Sure, you can create a jQeury plugin. Look at this link http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/advanced-plugin-concepts/. It is pretty straight forward. If you go this route, it will be easy to rename the attrs for entire collections, the way other jQuery functions work.

Comment: Sorry I was meant to be doing this, but ran out of time. So I just went with your above method which works perfectly anyway... Why change a good thing? :)