# Change a html5 Data-Attribute

Tags: jquery

Hi i have some problems with this code.

i use this to store a offset value for database offset

```
button.remove('data-offset');
button.attr('data-offset', comoffset);
```

the first time my script is triggerd, the button gets the new data and all is fine. but on the second or third time, the data offset never will be replaced again...

i used this code from : [change data-attribute using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18751450/change-data-attribute-using-jquery/41896869#41896869)

Edit1: The Complete Code

```
if (busy == false) {
        busy = true;
        comoffset = button.data('offset');
        comoffset = comoffset + comlimit;
        button.removeAttr('data-offset');
        button.attr('data-offset', comoffset);
        // start to load the next set of data
        setTimeout(function() { displayComments(comlimit, comoffset,chat); }, 1000);
    }
```

Comment: Can you show the complete code?

Answer (score 0):

Please use removeAttr function to remove any arrtibute from inside tag

```
button.removeAttr('data-offset');
```

Comment: i testet it but the data-offset will only one times removed and set new

Comment: are you try to use, button.data('offset', 123);

Comment: not solved the problem... when i first remote and that attr the data, its ok for the first time. but at the second run the data will be the same...

Answer (score 0):

First, remove the attr

```
button.removeAttr('data-offset');
```

then use:

```
button.attr('data-offset', comoffset);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `removeAttr()` for removing an attribute

```
button.removeAttr('data-offset');
```

You can use `attr()` to set an attribute

```
button.attr('data-offset', comoffset);
```