# How to change the attribute using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this tag

```
<div data-type="move" >some text</div>
```

How can I change the attribute so that it is

```
<div data-ty="move" >some text</div>
```

Comment: I think you must remove the attr first and then add a newer one like suggested here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/317170/how-can-i-change-html-attribute-names-with-jquery . Example for your specific case: https://jsfiddle.net/briosheje/zcc04yz2/ . that's probably a duplicate though :)

Answer (score 2):

Remove the existing attribute and add new

```js
$('[data-type]').each(function() { // get all elemnts which have the attribute `data-type` and iterate over them
  var temp = $(this).data('type'); // get the existing element attribute value
  $(this)
    .removeAttr('data-type') // remove the attribute
    .attr('data-ty', temp); // add new attribute with value of existing
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-type="move">some text</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just 2 lines:

```
<div class="myDiv" data-type="move" >some text</div>

$('.myDiv').removeAttr('data-type'); // first remove old attribute
$('.myDiv').attr('data-ty',"move"); // now add new attribute
```

Comment: This will add the `data-ty` attribute to every div on the page.

Comment: as OP has not mentioned any class in div..it will the answer.. but for his reference he can also add class to that div and using its class he can add attribute to div