# How to change psudo element content based on ID in CSS

Tags: jquery, css

```
<span id="opensidebarid" class="icon"></span>
```

CSS:

```
.icon:before {
   content: 'close';
}
```

I want to change the content of `:before` using the ID from JavaScript (jQuery). How it is possible? I have tried with `prop` but not working at all.

Comment: Somebody already answered this on this question -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/317170/how-can-i-change-html-attribute-names-with-jquery

Comment: Read more about jQuery `.css` here => [css](https://api.jquery.com/css/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change CSS using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730035/how-to-change-css-using-jquery)

Comment: May be you can't understand my question.
This is not just changing CSS using jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set an attribute in your css to get content data from there and then you can change that attribute using `jQuery`, since you cannot change the content of a `:before` element directly:

CSS:

```
.icon:before {
   content: attr(data);
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $elem = $("#opensidebarid"); // Get element by ID.
  elemClass = $elem.attr("class"); // Get the class of that element in order to change content.
  $('.' + elemClass).attr('data', "open"); // Change attribute value of content.
});
```

Comment: It's really perfect answer! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

After thinking a bit, I understood your question.
::before is a pseudo-selector, not a DOM element. So you can’t select it via jQuery.

You can toggleClass via jQuery if would like to change the ::before.

You could change it by creating a toggle class.
For example:

```
.icon-toggle {content: "example" !important}
```

Then you can create either onclick or some action to toggle the change.

```
$("#opensidebarid").toggleClass("icon-toggle")
```

If you could write more detailed question I could help you more.

Comment: Then how can I change it?

Comment: I have edited my answer, please check. And also give more detailed information If you could of what you're trying to do.